# Gradle release plugin which modify version in gradle.properties can support Jfrog artifactory publish with release version

Tags: git, gradle, artifactory, gradle-release-plugin

All steps required are below.

1. remove '-SNAP' suffix from the version and commit to git repo
2. create new git tag on this commit
3. Artifactory Deploy on Jfrog with release version not with -SNAP version
4. bump version in build.gradle (like pom.xml), and add '-SNAP' suffix.

I used the most popular Gradle Release Plugin (https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) but not able to deploy artifactory on Jfrog with release version (it's always taking SNAP version).

Below is my sample code...

gradle.build file

```
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'in.org'
            artifactId 'some-service'
            version "${version}"
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = version.endsWith('SNAP') ? "${snapshot_repository}" : "${release_repository}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publications("mavenJava")
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = "${release_repository}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

release {
    versionPropertyFile = 'gradle.properties'
    failOnCommitNeeded = false
    failOnPublishNeeded = false
    git {
        requireBranch.set('release')
    }
}

artifactoryDeploy.shouldRunAfter preTagCommit, checkCommitNeeded

updateVersion.doLast {
    def buildGradle = file('gradle.properties')
    buildGradle.text = buildGradle.text.replaceFirst(~/version = (\d++\.\d++\.\d++)/, 'version = \'$1\'')
}
```

gradle.properties file

```
artifactory_user=*****
artifactory_password=*****
artifactory_contextUrl=https://jfrog.in/artifactory
version=1.0.1-SNAPSHOT
snapshot_repository=gradle-dev-local
release_repository=gradle-release-local
```

Comment: Are you opposed to moving to the maven-publishing repository?  I've found that it's far superior to the Artifactory plugin.

Comment: How we can use maven-publishing repository here? We are using gradle in our projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to make project module version dynamic based on environment. If env is prod we should remove -SNAP from the version as mentioned below.

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.7.9")
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '4.29.0')
        classpath 'net.researchgate:gradle-release:3.0.2'
    }
}
    
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'

def springboot_version = '2.7.3'
def environment = hasProperty('env') ? env : null
def artifactory_publish_version = "${environment}" != "prod" ? "${version}" : "${version}".replace("-SNAP", "")

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { //Url for local dependencies in dev/qa env
        url "${artifactory_contextUrl}/gradle-dev-local"
        credentials {
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
        }
    }
}
def artifactory_publish_version = "${environment}" != "prod" ? "${version}" : "${version}".replace("-SNAP", "")

configurations { // this needs to be add for springboot projects
   [apiElements, runtimeElements].each {
       it.outgoing.artifacts.removeIf 
       { it.buildDependencies.getDependencies(null).contains(jar) }
       it.outgoing.artifact(bootJar)
   }
}

jar {
    enabled = false
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'your-org'
            artifactId 'your-service'
            version "${artifactory_publish_version}"
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "${artifactory_contextUrl}"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = artifactory_publish_version.endsWith('SNAP') ? "${snapshot_repository}" : "${release_repository}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
        defaults {
            publications("mavenJava")
            publishArtifacts = true
            publishPom = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = "${release_repository}"
            username = "${artifactory_user}"
            password = "${artifactory_password}"
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

release { // To create git tag
    git {
        requireBranch.set('release')
    }
}
```